# I HAVE TRY EVERY THING WITH THIS PIP BROKEN PROBLEM

Tags: python, pip

every time in i have this problem i just copy my files and install a fresh copy of kali and work again to update the system and copy redownload the requirement for my application i don't know exactly where or when its happened the only work around to use environment active pip3 works fine

```
root@kali:~# which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
root@kali:~# whereis pip
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 
/usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz



root@kali:~# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==18.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 487, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2728, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2346, in load
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2352, in resolve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/download.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-18.0.0-py2.7.egg/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-18.0.0-py2.7.egg/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, serialization
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_init_cffi_1_0_external_module'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Why have you included traceback? What is the exact error? Why are you setting up a python development environment in Kali? Why are you not using a `requirements.txt` for your python application?

Comment: @jasonwryan it was working fine until something go wrong

Comment: @kemotep i have used requirements.txt for every application alone i have try uninstall and reinstall it back with no luck

Comment: @KhaledAlajmi I would say user Claus Andersen's answer will fix pip. If you are using Kali Linux there maybe an issue with their implementation of pip or python.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a general python issue.

Answer (score 4):

If pip is messed up. Then the best bet is to use the same package system you used to install python on your distribution to re-install it.

The next step is to get the [python environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) to fix it itself using:

```
python -m ensurepip

python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

If that fails you can try the [bootstrap script](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) - get it with curl:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

And then execute:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: its throw the same error when i try to install get-pip.py after download it with curl but i think its path error now i see this its seem that they have different path 
    $which pip
    /usr/local/bin/pip
    $whereis pip
    pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz

    $which pip3
    /usr/bin/pip3
    $whereis pip3
    pip3: /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz

Comment: I think you have a mixed python 2/3 installation. Try `python3 -m ensurepip` or `python3 get-pip.py`

Comment: i wanna say thank you for the replay i did try the - python3 get-pip.py and work like magic thank you for the replay and the help 

thanks for all who try to help .

Comment: @KhaledAlajmi Please mark the answer as "accepted" so that other users would easily find it. :)